# Android log4j Logging Multiple times

Tags: java, android, logging

Hi Guys got a issue here using Log4j.

My code is

```
public class MyLogger{
    private static Logger mLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyLogger.class);

    public static void configure() {
        LogConfigurator logConfigurator = new LogConfigurator();
        logConfigurator.setFileName(getLogPath());
        logConfigurator.setRootLevel(Level.DEBUG);
        logConfigurator.setLevel("com.**", Level.ALL);
        logConfigurator.setMaxFileSize(1024 * 1024 * 5);
        logConfigurator.configure();
    }

    public static void info(String msg) {
        mLogger.info(msg);
    }

    public static void warn(String msg) {
        mLogger.warn(msg);
    }

    public static void debug(String msg) {
        mLogger.debug(msg);
    }

    public static void error(String msg) {
        mLogger.error(msg);
    }
```

This code works but as I noticed it is logged multiple times. I tried reading some tutorial here and they say that I need to add **additivity="false"** but that function is not available on Jar file.

Comment: The Logger class has `setAdditivity` derived from `Category`. Did you try that?

Comment: @Fildor what do you mean by Category? So far what I did is add the jar file and create that class. Do I need to create a category?

Comment: No, `Category` is the deprecated predecessor of `Logger` class. It inherits `setAdditivity` method. So if you configure your loggers programmatically, you should be able to set this property by using `mLogger.setAdditivity(false)`. Not sure if this must be done before logging the first time, though.

Answer (score 0):

Each enabled logging request for a given logger will be forwarded to all the appenders in that logger, as well as the appenders higher in the hierarchy.

Check log4j.properties and make the change to have it set to false :

```
log4j.additivity.com.javacodegeeks.examples.log4jadditivity.theClass=false
```